# How to disable Windows 8 lock screen?

Tags: windows-8-preview, lock-screen

So I took a plunge and installed Windows 8 Consumer Preview on my main home PC. So far so good, but there is one annoyance - the system "locks" the computer after a period of inactivity causing me to re-enter my password.

I really would like to avoid this, but have no idea how. I already tried the power settings (no pass on wake up) and the screen saver settings with no luck. Is this some sort of bug, or am I missing something?

P.S. In this case I favor convenience over security.

Comment: Set the period of time before the lockscreen appears.  Use the same procedure you would use for Windows 7.

Comment: How?
I tried settings on the props page for Screen Saver and Power Options. Is there a different place?

Answer (score 13):

Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\System Settings
click "change settings that are currently unavailable" and than choose at 
password protection on wakeup "don't require a password"

Answer (score 6):

You can get rid of the lock screen (before the login prompt) by means of a policy change. Start `gpedit.msc`, then go to `Computer Configuration` -> `Administrative Templates` -> `Control Panel` -> `Personalization` and in the left pane double-click the setting `Do not display the lock screen` and set it to `Enabled`.

Copied from another answer by me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033754).

Comment: gpedit.msc does not exist for me, other suggestions?

Comment: @PsychoDad: see the [other answer](http://superuser.com/a/517543/68747) in that case.

Comment: @PsychoDad gpedit.msc needs Windows Pro resp. Windows Enterprise.

Answer (score 3):

Type "EAS" in the Metro Start Screen and click Settings on the right side. From there you can reset the EAS Policies. This will help if you have connected a mail account which enforces some security policies.

If you have a non-english Windows installed try the following (instead of typing EAS):
Win+X and open Control panel > Control Panel > User Accounts > Reset Security Policies.

After this, you should be able to disable the requirement for password under PC Settings → User.

Comment: You don't need to disable the password.  The user just doesn't want the Start Screen to appear after a period of inactivity.

Answer (score 2):

Check under power options. Setting --> control panel --> System and Security --> Power Options--> Password protection on wakeup

Comment: If it isn't obvious, click the "Change options currently unavailable" if you want to change Pass protection.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug, at least on my installation If i change the screen saver timeout from the default 5 mins to anything else then click OK or Apply and come back to Screen saver settings it has reverted back to 5 mins

Comment: Saw the same behavior but I don't think we're talking about the screensaver here. It's more about the lock screen of Win8

Answer (score 0):

(Posting this answer for searchability)

The answer on this page (http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-lock-screen-in-windows-8/) worked for others in my organization, but not for me.  The solution there was:

> METHOD 1: Using Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc)
>
> 1. Press "WIN+R" key combination to launch RUN dialog box then type gpedit.msc and press Enter. > It'll open Group Policy Editor.
> 2. Now go to: Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Control Panel -> Personalization
> 3. double-click on "Do not display the lock screen" option and set its value to "Enabled".
>
> METHOD 2: Using Registry Editor (regedit)
>
> 1. Set via regedit: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization
> 2. create a new DWORD NoLockScreen and set its value to 1

NB: I'm running OSX, and then a Windows 8 VM with Parallels.  [@teeney-weeny's solution](https://superuser.com/a/517543/165685) worked for me since the Parallels profile had some overrides.

Admittedly, my current environment has a cumulative solution (method 1 + method 2 + @teeney-weeny's solution).

Answer (score -1):

Right click on desktop and click personalize and go to click screen saver and check the dialog box on resume display logon screen