# How to disable the start screen on Windows 8 Release Preview?

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, windows-8-preview

The [old advice](http://youtu.be/06wXGIcdlb4) to set the `REG_DWORD` value named `RPEnabled` (some sources claim it's `RPEnable`) under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer` to `0` doesn't work anymore since the *Consumer Preview* (i.e. now also for the *Release Preview*). Yes, I tried both `RPEnabled` and `RPEnable`.

How can I log into the system and be presented the desktop instead of the metro start screen? I got rid of the lock screen already, so this is the missing piece in the puzzle of making Windows 8 *Release Preview* usable.

Comment: How did you disable the lock screen?

Comment: @Moab: linking only inside SuperUser now http://superuser.com/questions/398015 - see my answer there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create an Explorer script file that launches the desktop. Open Notepad and paste or type in the following text:

   ```
   [Shell]
   Command=2
   IconFile=Explorer.exe,3
   [Taskbar]
   Command=ToggleDesktop
   ```

   Save the file as `showmydestkop.scf` and put it in a location you’ll easily remember.
2. Launch Windows Task Scheduler. You can find Task Scheduler by using Windows 8's built-in search or by navigating to the Administrative Tools section of Control Panel.

   1. Select Task Scheduler Library in the left window pane.

      [image]
   2. Right click in the task area and select Create New Task.

      [image]
   3. Enter a name (ex: ShowDesktop)  on the General tab.

      [image]
   4. Set the task to trigger at log on by clicking new on the trigger tab, and selecting  "At log on" from the Begin Task list.

      [image]
   5. Make your script an action by clicking New on the Action tab, selecting  "Start a program" from the Action menu, and entering the full path of `showmydesktop.scf` (ex: `C:\myscripts\showmydesktop.scf`) in the Program/script field.

      [image]
   6. Toggle off "Stop if the computer switches to battery power" on the conditions tab. You want to log in to the desktop whether your notebook is plugged in or not.

      [image]
   7. Click Ok and close the Task Manager.

The next time you log in, whether at boot up or after log out, the desktop will launch shortly after the Metro screen loads.

[Source of Information](http://blog.laptopmag.com/6-ways-to-totally-avoid-metro-and-use-only-desktop-mode-in-windows-8/2)

EDIT: If you also want the classic XP start menu on the Desktop, [install Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Wow, this is cool. I've got to look into Task Scheduler.

Comment: @Moab: +1 for getting me closer. It's not exactly a solution since it opens Explorer with the *Libraries* folder. So I'd be exchanging one annoyance for another (not using Windows Explorer normally). However, I reckon the solution can be adapted to start any other desktop program in its stead and thus show the desktop immediately. Thanks. Won't accept for the moment in case someone comes up with an even better solution.

Comment: There has to be a way to just toggle it to the desktop, but have not found that out yet.

Answer (score 2):

Using AutoHotkey, you can create an application that minimizes the Start Screen on log-in.
Create an ahk text file with the two lines below, compile it with Autohotkey and add the compiled application as a scheduled task using the method above.

```
WinWaitActive Start menu ahk_class ImmersiveLauncher
WinMinimizeAll
```

Answer (score 1):

Stardock's [Start8](http://www.stardock.com/products/start8/) works on the Preview Release. It's simple and effective solution to the problem that is full-screen Metro.

[image: Start8 start-menu]

#### Features

- Adds a “Start” menu to the Windows 8 taskbar
- Enables quick access and searching of your installed applications
- Adds Run... option via right-click menu
- Adds Shutdown... option via right-click menu
- Choose a custom Start button image

Answer (score 1):

Nothing works better as [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/). RPEnabled is not present in Windows 8 so go with that tool and you get a nice old style - desktop (not touch adapted to desktop) interface.