# Getting rid of Metro interface

Tags: windows-8-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable the start screen on Windows 8 Release Preview?](https://superuser.com/questions/431636/how-to-disable-the-start-screen-on-windows-8-release-preview)

The company I work for primarily runs Windows XP machine. These machines are getting old and need to be replaced. I wanted to wait until Windows 8 was released since it is right around the corner. So, I have downloaded Windows 8 to test run and figure out the problems I am going to have with my users, programs, goup policy, and etc.

After installing I noticed pretty much everything has changed and I was a bit lost for awhile. In my opinion the Metro interface sucks and is definitely going to frustrate my users. If they are not comfortable using it they are going to be bugging me frequently. Not to mention it is going to cause numerous amendments to our group policy.

Overall I think it could be time consuming to support. So, I was wondering if there was a way to disable the Metro interface and show a traditional start button on the desktop. I would like to do this without a hack if at all possible.

Comment: I found your answer at [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10035024/225522). Not sure as to why it was asked and answer there but I think it more of SuperUser question than SO.

Comment: Yeah, just looking for a different perspective.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I apologize if this is blunt, but what you are suggesting is a terrible idea.  Please consider the following points.

1. Brand new operating systems are not really a good idea, especially ones that don't appear to be built for business.
2. Going from XP directly to 8 is going to confuse all of your users just as it made you a little lost.
3. No, so far as I know, there is no way to do a classic feel.  There is no more start menu in the traditional sense.
4. If you are moving from XP to any windows system, please make it Windows 7.  Do your users, and yourself a favor and avoid Windows 8 until it is proven.

Newer is not **always** better.

Comment: In time all of your users will come to know Microsoft's new approach. I would suggest waiting until that time before making the harsh upgrade. Windows 7 is a much better OS than windows XP. If you are itching for an upgrade, I'd agree that this is the way to start.

Comment: I agree with you newer is not always better that is why I was trying it out for myself before I throw it at my users.  We run a lot of specialized programs and many of them won't even run on Windows 7 without being in XP Mode.  Even then some of the functionality is lost.  I will have to upgrade eventually though since Windows XP EOL is right around the corner.

Comment: Ideally I would like to through them all on Ubuntu.  But they would definitely rebel.

Comment: @Linger - XP EOL is around the corner, but it'll still be usable if need be.  Please dont subject your users to Windows 8 yet.  And man oh man, if they arent linux people, definitely do not subject them to linux.  Everyone will be completely lost.

Comment: @francisswest - I wouldn't put them on Linux, that would abuse me as well.  They would be constantly bothering me asking for help.  XP will be usable after EOL, however security updates will cease.  Right now they are running Pentium 4 machines maxed out with 1GB of RAM.  I used nLite awhile ago to strip most of what they didn't use and it made them run faster.  However, the machines are growing tired and slowly starting to fail.

Comment: @Linger - Sounds like a good time to get an advance on your equipment budget.  If you are going to be doing a full deployment with new computers and new operating systems....might as well do it all at once.  Its gonna be a couple weeks to a couple of months of hell.  But computers that will last for the next 6 years, with an OS that will work well for your users and yourself will all be well worth it.

Good Luck!

Comment: @francisswest I went through the same all at once upgrade back in 2005.  I definitely know what to expect.

Comment: You might be better off waiting until Windows 8 is released, purchasing Windows 8 licenses, then exercising your windows downgrade rights to install Windows 7. Let the users get accustomed to Windows 7, and then once Windows 8 matures a bit more, eventually work on transitioning to 8.