# How skip Windows 8 Consumer Preview Start Screen On Startup and jump directly to desktop

Tags: windows-8-preview, modern-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable the start screen on Windows 8 Release Preview?](https://superuser.com/questions/431636/how-to-disable-the-start-screen-on-windows-8-release-preview)

Unlike previous versions of Windows where you are taken to desktop at system startup, Windows 8 welcomes you with Metro Start Screen, providing quick access to applications and system shortcuts, pinned programs, and so on. Apparently, Windows 8 doesn’t allow users to bring the classic Windows Startup behavior back. If you don’t want to click the Desktop metro tile every time after logging into Windows, how to bypass Metro Start Screen and jump to desktop directly?

I really wish auto login windows classic windows desktop when start or reboot windows 8 OS, i have tried out below way:
  [2]:change Registry:
  It switches the RPEnabled string to either 0 (inactive) or 1 (active) under  KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer

result fail,start or reboot windows 8 OS and cannot directly to classic desktop.

OS: windows 8 Release Preview Build 8400 32-bit
UUT: dell laptop
BIOS: legacy or UEFI　mode

Comment: At any rate, you will find a solution from @Moab there, since the issue you are having is the same as the one that *that* peson was having.  I'm just not going to reprint that solution here.

Comment: could you give me link?,i want to verify solution of "Moab there". thanks!

Comment: he provides a link at the bottom of the instructions, it goes here http://blog.laptopmag.com/6-ways-to-totally-avoid-metro-and-use-only-desktop-mode-in-windows-8/2 but there is a second method detailed in this discussion thread http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itprogeneral/thread/ae120185-6401-4637-80d2-1bba4ac9d70b/#fe5b7bf9-f937-4dc5-8f01-547c3259a98c

Comment: Thanks, i have verify this solution ok, but it show Libraries dialog box when i go on desktop

Comment: Yeah, that was brought up in the original answer.  What about trying the other solution here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itprogeneral/thread/ae120185-6401-4637-80d2-1bba4ac9d70b/#fe5b7bf9-f937-4dc5-8f01-547c3259a98c