# Disable auto-lock on inactivity

Tags: windows, windows-8, security

How can I disable the automatic locking on idle mechanism in Windows 8? I have tried:

- Disabling screen saver and screen saver "lock on resume" --> done
- Disable lock on wake in power options --> done

I still cannot find a solution - it seems to lock after some period of inactivity.

Edit:

This is **NOT A DUPLICATE** - the answer and question marked as duplicate are both unrelated to the question. The question is to **disable auto-lock *not* to disable the screen before the password entry**.

Comment: Search the web for program called "caffeine", it simulates mouse movement and/or key presses periodically in order to fool windows and prevent locking. It's not perfect though. When you select some text with a mouse, when it kicks in, it unselects the text, so you need to select again. Also, in some terminal windows (e.g. PuTTY), it types a character shown as ~. Anyway, lacking other solutions, this could be sufficiently good

Comment: The existing duplicate (http://superuser.com/questions/398015/how-to-disable-windows-8-lock-screen?lq=1) was not completely relevant so I have pointed it at a more appropriate duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Open run command box by pressing [image] + <kbd>R</kbd> keys simultaneously. Type `gpedit.msc` in the box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

- On the Group Policy Editor, expand `Computer Configuration` -> `Administrative Templates` -> `Control Panel` and then click on `Personalization`.
- Now, on the right pane, double-click on `Do not display the lock screen` to enable or disable this feature.

  [image]

  [image]

Comment: I don't want to disable the screen before the login, I want to disable the automatic locking. Does this do this?

Comment: In this case you could try this answer http://superuser.com/a/1107767