# Windows 10 keeps logging me out after display turns off

Tags: windows-10

I'm having the same problem as [this guy](https://superuser.com/questions/954467/windows-10-auto-logout-on-5-minutes-of-inactivity). No answer was found on his topic, so I hope someone will be able to help.

In my Power Options I have set the screen to `Turn off after 5 minutes` and to `never sleep`. Closing the lid is also set to `Do Nothing`. I also checked the screen saver settings, that the `On resume, display log-on screen` might be checked, but it isn't.

I'm guessing it's an issue with the `Turn off the display` option?

*Extra: I altered my screen to turn off after 1 minute, for sake of testing. As soon as the display turns off and I move the mouse relatively quickly (within 2 seconds), the screen turns on normally, anything later and I need to login again.*

*Also I am logged in on a AD domain. I'm not sure if this holds certain security settings like this?*

Comment: This setting can be overridden by a domain policy. Is your pc part of a corporate network?

Comment: Yes (I'm one of the admins :D), but I can't remember our domain policy having one. Do you know what it's called? I'll Google it and verify against our domain controller.

Comment: I think I've found it, seems to be working now .. Wasn't the domain, was a local setting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `System>Accounts>Sign-in Options` and where you have the option `Require Sign-in`, select `Never`. I had it set to `When PC wakes up from sleep`. Makes no sense to me as the computer never went into sleep mode, it's just the screen that got turned off.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could this be because you have a screensaver set?  Screensavers can be configured to prompt for a password on resuming and this is possibly the cause of your issue.

Go to Start > Settings > Personalisation > Lock Screen > "Screen saver settings":
[image]

When in the screensaver applet, make sure that the "on resume, display logon screen" isn't selected:
[image]

While your acreensaver might not be active, in a brief test I just did, having this box ticked with the screensaver set to "none" caused me to get a password prompt on my laptop when my screen turned off.

Comment: the checkbox On resume, display logon screen is unchecked. I don't have a screensaver set. I checked it, applied the settings and unchecked it again, to see if that maybe helps (but it didn't :().