# How do I get a service to auto run without logging in one time to get the service running?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Please don't chastise me for windows 2008. It's not my choice. It will go away soon.

I have a virtual machine image that I copy and start. The service will run, but only after I log in once.

Is there a autorun location that I can place the file or short cut in to make this work?

I just need a short-term hack.

More data: I'm supporting a really old copy of the software - ManageEngine Desktop Central 9 - for a very short period of time. We run this on an old windows 2008 server. I have it deep inside of a the network with no Internet connectivity, so it is insecure but protected.

I just need a short-term hack.

I'm willing to do the reading if somebody will point me to resources but I don't even know what to look up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set autologin from [netplwiz](https://www.lifewire.com/how-do-i-auto-login-to-windows-2626066), then [log it back out](https://superuser.com/questions/954467/windows-10-auto-logout-on-5-minutes-of-inactivity) after a very short period.
Your scripts will then run.

Comment: Works and has great step-by-step. THX